# Access element of a list in DAX - PowerBI

Tags: powerbi, dax, measure

I have a very "simple" question that I couldn't find an answer anywhere..

Is there a way to access an element of a list like in any programming language? i.e:

```
Custom Measure =

VAR _list = {"UP","DOWN","NORMAL"}
VAR _count = SUM(something)
VAR _cond = IF(_count > 10, _list[0], IF(_count < 10, _list[1], _list[2]))

RETURN
   _cond
```

I need something like the code above but I found no way to access the elements of my list "on demand" like that.. Is something like that even possible in DAX?

Comment: DAX doesn't work this way. This sounds like https://xyproblem.info/

Comment: What is your "list"? Is it a column in a table, or as above?

Comment: my "list" is literally a VAR I created on the spot

Comment: @DavideBacci I'm not sure how "DAX Works" thats the reason for the question, if DAX doesn't work like that and its not possible, nice, good to know its not possible and I move on to solve my problem using another method.. but if its possible I'd like to now "How".. and that's what I haven't found anywhere the "IF its possible" and the "HOW to do it".

Comment: in fact, I already solved my problem using another method but it requires lots of "text repetition" that if I want/need to change later I'll have to manually edit it everywhere again.. that's the reason I was looking for a way to "reuse" my text putting it all in one place that I can easily see and edit later

Comment: Normal programming patterns don't translate well to DAX - it is a completely different paradigm. I suggest some reading on SQLBI.com

Comment: got it, I'll have to "rewire" my brain a bit, I'm too used to thinking/following these patterns.. will take some time to get used to.. I'll take a look at the mentioned article to see if I can better understand how dax works and how to "translate" what I'm thinking/need